# Gunzip in range of files

Tags: gzip

I'm running a long copy of .gz files from one server to another. At the same time, I'd like to unzip the files already copied. For example, al filenames that start with `a` through filenames starting with `c`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @FaMonttyN2 look at this http://linux.icydog.net/ssh/piping.php some of these lines might be what you need. you can embed the tar command on the ssh using "' '"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use your shell. Assuming a relatively modern shell (such as bash), you can do

```
gunzip [a-c]*gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
for file in [a-c]*.gz; do gunzip "$file"; done
```

or even `gunzip [a-c]*.gz` (thanks for a reminder @terdon).

If you are doing this just to reduce network traffic, it would make much more sense to just compress the connection stream, or even better, use `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely unzip all files which have been completely copied. So the task is to determine which files are complete.

Let's assume that the directory is empty before the copying starts and that the unzipped files are written to a different directory. One possibility to determine which files are ready for unzipping is to wait for the next file.

If that is a relevant approach for you then I can provide some code for that.